# Input float won't clear

Tags: html, css

In my css file I have set my inputs to float right. But right now I don't want it to float anymore. I don't want to delete it from my css file. Right now I am using overflow:auto and it's not doing anything. Everbody knows that overflow:auto; is supposed to stop a float.

Here is the html without all the clutter

```
<div class="input_area">
            <label id="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" />

         </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.input_area{height:40%; width:40%;  margin-left:10%; background-color:#00BBBB;   }
 input { overflow: auto; }
```

If you need more html let me know.

Comment: If you read the very first sentence it says it's in the css file.  I am only including the ones between the style tag.  Do you want me to include the css file?

Comment: Thank You. So what exactly is overflow:auto for anyways?

Comment: overflow:auto; "If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content" - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: That's for clearing floats by use of the parent rather than a sibling with the clear property

Comment: @redelman431: It's a bit late now, but the context can play a huge role. Google "CSS selector specificity".